# phpStorm leaving tab out of paren block like in eclipse

Tags: phpstorm

Is there a way in phpstorm to get outside of the last automatically inserted paren or bracket.

For example in eclipse.  If I type a '(' it will auto insert a ')' and move my cursor in between them.  When I am done editing with them I can simple hit tab to move the cursor just outside of the ')'.

This does not seem to work in phpStorm and I can't find an equivalent.

Is there a way to do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you type an extra closing brace again, it will not be inserted and the caret will move outside of the parenthesis.

Comment: but pressing tab is a lot faster than typing the parentheses or quotes or curly brackets (let alone a combination of the above). So is there a way to get tab to work the same way as it does in eclipse?